# TYPO3: Form element.textarea-1.properties.defaultValue translation

Tags: forms, localization, typo3

I'm working on translating a TYPO3 form.

All works like a charm, only the defaultValue attibute don't.

This is the relevant part of the form definition:
`

```
renderingOptions:
  templateVariant: version2
  submitButtonLabel: Abschicken
type: Form
identifier: productformular
label: 'Formular Produktseite'
prototypeName: standard
renderables:
  -
    renderingOptions:
      previousButtonLabel: 'Previous step'
      nextButtonLabel: 'Neue Seite'
    type: Page
    identifier: page-1
    label: Produktanfrage
    renderables:
      -
        defaultValue: 'Guten Tag, ich interessiere mich für dieses Gerät. Bitte melden Sie sich schnellstmöglich bei mir.'
        type: Textarea
        identifier: textarea-1
        label: Nachricht
        properties:
          fluidAdditionalAttributes:
            placeholder: 'Ihre Nachricht an uns'
```

`

Unfortunately, I can't find a hint in any instructions on how to translate the defaultValue.

Has anybody a soilution for me?

I tryed something like
`

```
<trans-unit id="productformular.element.textarea-1.properties.label">
   <source>Message</source>
</trans-unit>
<trans-unit id="productformular.element.textarea-1.properties.placeholder">
   <source>Your message to us</source>
</trans-unit>
<trans-unit id="productformular.element.textarea-1.properties.defaultValue">
   <source>Hello, I am interested in this device. Please contact me as soon as possible.</source>
</trans-unit>
```

`
Label and placeholder are translated, but defaultValue doesn't.

Comment: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/97637 there is an issue about it not being possible? Maybe translate frontend with javascript if it is not possible...

Comment: or different form per language, good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of a solution with XLIFF. But you can use [Form variants](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-form/main/en-us/I/Concepts/Variants/Index.html) to override the defaultValue:

```
-
  defaultValue: 'Max Powers'
  identifier: name
  label: Name
  type: Text
  variants:
    - identifier: defaultValue-for-de
      condition: 'siteLanguage("twoLetterIsoCode") == "de"'
      defaultValue: 'Max Mustermann'
```

Comment: Form variants I did not know until now.
This seems to be the best solution for my problem.
Thank you sebkln

Answer (score 0):

As described in Rustyjim's post, TYPO3 does not (yet) provide this possibility.

I didn't want different forms per language, also a javascript solution didn't seem to fit for this.

I solved it now using the form view helper and the standard fluid translate function:

```
        <formvh:render
        persistenceIdentifier="EXT:liftfinder/Resources/Private/Forms/productContactForm.form.yaml"
        overrideConfiguration="{
          renderables: {
            0: {
              renderables: {
                4: {
                  defaultValue: '{f:translate(key: \'textarea-1_defaultValue\')}'
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }"
    />
```

It's not really a good solution either, because the elements are addressed by a sequence number instead of a unique identifier.

Better solutions are welcome.